# UTC javascript countdown goes negative in browser

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to make a JavaScript countdown timer to UTC midnight that works in a browser (which typically converts to local time).

It seems to work most of the time, but for some reason it will go negative sometimes.  I want it to always display time until midnight UTC.

`-3 hours 23 minutes 34 seconds`

I'm pretty sure I tested this on crossing midnight, but lately it's been going negative like it isn't pulling a new date.

Here is what I am using now on my website.

```
  setInterval(() => {
    let toDate = new Date()
    let tomorrow = new Date()
    tomorrow.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0)
    let diffMS =
      tomorrow.getTime() / 1000 -
      toDate.getTime() / 1000 -
      toDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60
    let diffHr = Math.floor(diffMS / 3600)
    diffMS = diffMS - diffHr * 3600
    let diffMi = Math.floor(diffMS / 60)
    diffMS = diffMS - diffMi * 60
    let diffS = Math.floor(diffMS)
    let result = diffHr + ' hours '
    result += diffMi + ' minutes '
    result += diffS + ' seconds '
    this.timeRemaining = result
  }, 1000)
```

Comment: why not use the `UTC` methods of date rather than messing around with timezone offsets

Comment: In a place that observes daylight saving, on the days of the changeover the offset at the beginning of the day is different to the offset at the end of the day. Also, *diffMS* should probably be called *diffSecs*.

Comment: I think the reason it "sometimes goes negative" is because of your timezone - are you west or east of UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly where your issue is from, but using local time adjusted by offset is somewhat fraught. Also the offset changes over a DST boundary so that might be an issue too (or not) so the countdown will jump the equivalent of the change in offset (either + or -).

It's very much simpler to set the end using UTC methods and count down to that, e.g.

```js
// Return time to next UTC midnight as x hours x minutes x seconds
function toMidnightUTC(date = new Date()) {
  let d = new Date(+date);
  d.setUTCHours(24,0,0,0);
  let diff = d - date;
  return `${diff/3.6e6 |0} hours ` +
         `${diff%3.6e6 / 6e4 |0} minutes ` +
         `${diff%6e4 / 1000 |0} seconds`;
}

// Run  20ms after next full second
let runIt = ()=> {
  document.getElementById('s0').textContent = toMidnightUTC();
  let lag = 1020 - new Date() % 6e4;
  setTimeout(runIt, lag);
};

// Start the process…
runIt();
```

```html
<span id="s0"></span>
```

Note that *setInterval* isn't a good way to do a countdown as the interval is not guaranteed to run every second and typically slowly drifts so it doesn't tick with the system clock and drifts, so skips a second from time to time.

Better to use setTimeout and get the time to the next full second each time so it runs very close to the system clock tick and rarely skips (though it still might if the system is working hard).

Comment: Thanks, this is a very helpful answer.